# Does SQLDeveloper support executing scripts?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was trying to follow some instructions today, and it starts with the comment

```
REM  In SQLPlus I manually copy in each line and execute it.
```

That's nice, I don't have SQLPlus, I have SQLDeveloper.  The lines that were pasted in were of the type:

```
@\\server\dir\dir\dir\commandfile1.txt;
COMMIT;
```

...etc.

It didn't like it when I tried that in a SQL window.  I opened up and pasted in the commands by hand, and it wasn't happy with that either.  (Did I mention that I'm not so good with this application nor Oracle, but that everyone else was out today?)  The files there started with code like:

```
rem
set echo on
rem
execute procedure_name ('parameter1', 'parameter2');
```

A co-worker did have SQLPlus, and together we got it resolved.  But, is there a way for me to do this with SQLDeveloper, so I'm not stuck if he's out too?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To run scripts in SQL Developer:

```
@"\Path\Scriptname.sql"
```

(You only need the quotes if there are any spaces)

You can set a default Path: Tools menu > Preferences > Database > Worksheet > Select default path to look for scripts

Answer (score 2):

I was looking through the help files and found how to do it in SQL Developer Concepts and Usage->Using the SQL Worksheet->Script Runner.

Basically, you have to precede the file name with an @.  For example @C:\MyScript\Script.sql.

You can then run a batch of them this way.  Note that the command doesn't seem to like spaces in the file path.

Answer (score 1):

For each file you need to run, find it and drop it into SQLDeveloper.  Run the script (F5) and then commit (F11).  This will work for some scripts, but not all.

Comment: As you said, it works for some, but not all.  I had to install SQL*Plus to do the rest.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer these days comes with another tool called [sqlcl](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/overview/index.html). This is a bit like SQLPlus but is actually using some bits from SQL Developer to give a compatible command line/scripting type interface.

You would be able to use it to execute sqlplus style commands without fighting the extras of the SQL Developer style GUI which can get confusing.

Look for it under wherever SQL Developer is sitting. If you don't have it there, you can download it and deploy it into your sqldeveloper folder.

Comment: The information provided is true but I don't see how it answers the original post.  It seems only mildly relevant to the title, ignores the question content and doesn't expand much beyond "there's a tool, it has a command line"

Comment: The user thinks they only have only has SQL Developer. If the installation is standard, they probably have SQLCL available as well which is explained by the link.

Comment: Ok. And are you implying that things the user asked about (eg running @\\server\dir\dir\dir\commandfile1.txt; ) can be done from SQLcl? That would make your point relevant. Would you go so far as to say that it can do that?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it using sqlcl in the same way how you would do it using SQL PLUS,  from command line:

```
sqlcl user/password@host:port:sid @file.sql
```

file should be in the same directory where sqlcl is.

This solution is the best option if you are trying to execute a lot of instruction on sql file.

Answer (score -2):

This would do it:

```
begin
    procedure_name ('parameter1', 'parameter2');
end;
/
```