# SQL query, oracle pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to create a table in oracle DB that the index is increasing by 1 on insertion.
I have the code that does it, first create table, then create sequence and finally create the trigger.
when I type them, one by one, into the Oracle SQL Developer, paste the create table lines and commit, then the rest, one by one, it works, but if i father them all, and click run script, it does not create the sequence + trigger. only the table.

i separate the commands with /
any other thoughts ? or reference to working script ?

thanks !

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/288988/does-sqldeveloper-support-executing-scripts

Comment: You need to provide the script you're attempting to run if you want to get any meaningful assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't need the `/` in a script. Just use `;` to separate statements.

```
create table ... ;

create sequence ... ;

create trigger ... ;
```

I think this should be enough to run in SQL Developer and sqlplus.

Comment: Thanks, on SQL Developer it worked fine without begin/end on every statement. just wrote the lines and separated with ;